# Fix slider issue in Jquery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a help on fixing the button.
Currently it is working fine in the mode of sliding.

**JSFIDDLE**

[**http://jsfiddle.net/aprd3vr4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/aprd3vr4/)

**Problem 1:**

when you click the button back, green button is going down and coming back.
how to fix this?

**Problem 2:**

when 'content' box (div) slides i need a proper width instead of "85%"
how to fix this?

Thanks in Advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="holdingbox ">   
    <div class="rightbox">          
        <div class=" content">          
            <div class="legendContainer">
                <div class="headerDiv">Status :</div>   
                <div class=" legend innerElement"><span class="Bad"></span> Bad</div>               
                <div class=" legend innerElement"><span class="Good"></span>Good</div>
                <div class="legend innerElement"><span class="Neutral"></span>Neutral</div>             
                <div class="legend innerElement"><span class="No-Status"></span>No status</div>
            </div>
            <div class="legendContainer1">
                <div class="headerDiv">Trends :</div>   
                <div class=" legend innerElement"><span class="downGood-Trend"></span>Up Bad</div>              
                <div class=" legend innerElement"><span class="downBad-Trend"></span>Down Bad</div>
                <div class="legend innerElement"><span class="upGood-Trend"></span>Up Good</div>                
                <div class="legend innerElement"><span class="upBad-Trend"></span>Up Bad</div>
                <div class="legend innerElement"><span class="Side-Trend"></span>Side</div>             
                <div class="legend innerElement"><span class="No-Trend"></span>No Trend</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <a class="leftbox" href="#">Legends</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.innerElement{  
display:inline-block;
padding: 2px 5px!important;
margin:0;
}
.legendContainer,.legendContainer1{
width: 95%;
background: #fff;
padding:3px 0px;
}
.legendContainer{
margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.legendContainer1{
margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.headerDiv{
color: #141414;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 32px;
padding: 0px 10px;
width: 10%;
font-weight: 700;
font-size:14px;
}
.holdingbox {
position: absolute;
top: 114px;
right: 0px;
}

.leftbox {
position: relative;
top: 42px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 15px;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
left:33px;
padding: 2px 18px 2px 18px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
float: right;
background: #2EAD13;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rightbox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
background: #3d3f49;
vertical-align: top;
height: 106px;
float: right;
top: -8px;
width:0%;
}
.content{
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
position: relative;
width: 700px;
height: 100px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.rightbox').width('0%');
 $('.leftbox').click( function() {       
     var toggleWidth1 = $('.holdingbox')[0].style.width == "90%" ? "0%" : "90%";
     var toggleWidth = $('.rightbox')[0].style.width == "85%" ? "0%" : "85%";
     $('.holdingbox').animate({ width: toggleWidth1 });
    $('.rightbox').animate({ width: toggleWidth });

});
```

Comment: Hi have a look at my answer. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Kumar let me try, i will test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in Jquery, fixed my slider

```
$('.leftbox').click( function() {       
     $('.rightbox').animate({width: 'toggle'}); 
});
```

JS FIDDLE
**http://jsfiddle.net/aprd3vr4/5/**

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you are making it so complicated. This is a simple way with animations:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".legends").click(function () {
    $("body").toggleClass("legendOpen");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
body {overflow: hidden;}
.legends {position: absolute; -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); -o-transform: rotate(90deg); right: -1.5em; top: 20%; background: #2EAD13; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 3px 7px; z-index: 9; -webkit-transition: all 1s; -o-transition: all 1s; transition: all 1s;}
.legendContainer {position: absolute; top: 20%; right: -215px; -webkit-transition: all 1s; -o-transition: all 1s; transition: all 1s;}
.legendContainer .legendBox {border: 1px solid #2EAD13; padding: 50px; margin-top: -49px;}

.legendOpen .legends {right: 191px;}
.legendOpen .legendContainer {right: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="legends">Legends</a>
<div class="legendContainer">
  <div class="legendBox">Legend Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried your solution, it is working fine. but i will get a horizontal scroll.
i can not inject to body, i need a container because it is top of many other divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/oy629ajb/4/

Comment: Definitely sure there won't be one.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa You forgot to give `body {overflow: hidden;}`. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/oy629ajb/10/

Comment: if i give overflow to body, other scolling items will not be shown. any other way ? please

Comment: `body {overflow-x: hidden;}` Use this to hide only the horizontal scrollbar. Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/oy629ajb/11/

Comment: Sorry, i tried. this property messing my whole code.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Can you share your full code in fiddle or something?

Comment: i fixed it myself. i appreciate your help. Thank you once again.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa That's great... `:)`